# ifconfig show unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 for usb modem

Tags: networking, 20.04, ip, usb-modem, ifconfig

I am using

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

when I do ifconfig -a usb modem show following output

```
wwan0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

how can i fix this issues, I have modem drivers multiple time